# php.exe из командной строки

Tags: php

Мне необходимо в программе, написанной на Qt C++, прогнать некоторый текст через php интерпретатор.

Для этого запускаю `php.exe <имя_файла_на_диске>`, на что он выводит в консоль результат. Этот вариант в целом устраивает, но не очень нравится необходимость записи текста на диск. Нет ли возможности задать `php.exe <содержимое_php_файла_в_виде_текста>` и получить результат?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, можно:

```
php -r "Здесь содержимое Вашего файла"
```

Необходимо учесть, что открывающий тег `<?php` и соответственно закрывающий - тут не нужны.

Если нужно прямо напрямую содержимое файла интерпретировать в PHP как есть без всяких ограничений, можно использовать `pipe`:

```
echo "Содержимое файла вместе с <?php ?>" | php
```

Как работают конвейеры в винде, я не знаю, поэтому тут уже сами думайте.

Comment: то есть, html + php в куче так не засунешь, верно?

Comment: смотря как HTML выводить.

Comment: Ну у меня обычные страницы с html-тегами и php-вставками. Получается что перед использованием `php -r` придется еще делать какие-то манипуляции с тестом. Наверное все же проще оставить как есть: записывать в файл и скармливать файл.

Comment: Обновил ответ: написал другой способ, который Вашу ситуацию обработает, но я хз, как пайпы в винде работают, будет или нет работать и как это модифицировать для винды.

Comment: надо спрашивать не "как пайпы работают в винде", а "как перенаправить ввод-вывод в Qt". Ответ - "`QProcess ` перенаправляет ввод-вывод по умолчанию". А как это делать в винде - это уже проблемы Qt.

Comment: @Александр перевожу для вас тут строчку с `echo`. Просто запустите php без параметров через `QProcess` и запишите ваш php-скрипт прямо внутрь как будто это файл.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov в таком случае php ждет прерывания программы по ctrl-c. что сделать программно затруднительно. Все-таки вариант с записью в файл остается самым простым.

Comment: @Александр не обязательно убивать его через `Ctrl+C` - корректнее закрыть входной поток через `QProcess.closeWriteChannel()`. Тем более, `Ctrl+C`"убивает" процесс сразу же, а конец потока - по завершению обработки, что куда полезнее.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov спасибо, это вроде бы решило проблему